# eclipse exported could not resolve org.eclipse.core.runtime

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am currently developing an application utilizing JDK 11 and incorporating Eclipse plugins. During the execution of the application, I have encountered an error (please see below for details).

```
!SESSION 2024-02-08 15:39:08.759 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.19
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=amd64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2024-02-08 15:39:56.733
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)";   visibility:="reexport"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
```

The development environment I am using is the 64-bit version of Eclipse. Also require plugin (org.eclipse.core.jobs & org.eclipse.core.runtime) version is present in plugin directory as well.
And Im using eclipse version 4.18

I am reaching out to inquire if anyone has experienced a similar issue. Could this problem potentially be related to plugin compatibility issues when running with JDK 11 on a 64-bit system?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Verified eclipse plugins version from plugin directory.

Comment: _"is present in plugin directory"_ is not enough. Please tell how you have built your application you execute (if you don't build it with [Tycho](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html), you're doing something wrong; modifying or adding JAR files in the `plugins` folder does not work).

Comment: The only supported way to build an RCP is using [tag:tycho], there are lots of things that need to be done to set the RCP up correctly. See [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)